# how to use strcpy on dynamic char * buffer

Tags: c++

Having trouble with allocating dynamic buffer data using strcpy (SIGSEGV (QT Linux))

```
 char ** data = new char *[10];
 int current = 0;

 char temp[20];
 std::cin >> temp;

 strcpy( data[ current++ ],  temp); //works(before edit) 
                                    //I saw SIGSEGV message only on dynamic input
                                    //that's why I was thinking it works

 char * dynamicTemp = new char [ 20 ];
 std::cin >> dynamicTemp;

 strcpy( data[ current++ ], dynamicTemp ); //SIGSEGV
```

How should i properly store data? 
It's just for knowledges, so no need for string examples.

Comment: `char ** data = new char *[10];` allocated 10 pointers to `char*`, but each of these pointer points to a random  location. So even `strcpy( data[ current++ ],  temp);` should not work.

Comment: @user1810087 How is this not C++.  `new` is only available in C++.

Comment: do you have to use c-arrays?

Comment: @NathanOliver sorry i didn't see the `std::cin` and `new`...

Comment: The line that says "//works" doesn't actually work, it's undefined. Not displaying any symptoms until later is one example of undefined behaviour.

Comment: yeah i found out it, but I have catched SIGSEGV only when used dynamic memmory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have allocated array of char pointers. You need to allocate memory for each of your strings, something like this:

```
char * dynamicTemp = new char [ 20 ];
std::cin >> dynamicTemp;
data[ current++ ]  = new char [ 20 ];
strcpy( data[ current ], dynamicTemp );
```

Comment: that's what i wanted, just `data[ current ] = new char[ strlen( temp ) ];
    strcpy( data[ current++ ],  data);` this how i used.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually allocated memory for the pointer in `data[current]` leading to *undefined behavior* (and one of the possible outcomes of UB is that sometimes it *seems* to work fine).

Either allocate memory and assign it to the pointer, or use `std::string` instead (which is my recommendation).

---

In modern C++ there's really little reason to use pointers at all these days, least of all for strings. Using pointers just creates problems like the one you have, and more. And using `std::string` also means you won't have the risk of a buffer overflow if the user inputs a string longer than 19 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are dereferencing a pointer to unallocated memory.

```
 char ** data = new char *[10];
 strcpy( data[ current++ ],  temp); //works
```

`data[ current++ ]` is pointing to unallocated memory.

The other problem with the code is uncontrolled `strcpy` and cin reads. You have no guarantee whatsoever the user input fits into your buffers.